# How many times was Obi-Wan less than honest with Luke?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, obi-wan-kenobi

Despite his attempts to persuade Luke otherwise<sup>1</sup>, Obi-Wan is often less than entirely honest with Luke.  Sometimes he stretches the truth, sometimes he omits important details in such a way that Luke is misled, and it could be argued that on occasion, he tells flat-out lies.

Some of these less-than-entirely-true statements are glaring and staggering, like the "Your dad is dead and Darth Vader killed him" thing.  Others are less significant and easier to overlook<sup>2</sup>, like this bit of misinformation from *A New Hope*:

> **OBI-WAN**:  I haven't gone by the name Obi-Wan since oh, *before you were born*.

Granted, Obi-Wan may have adopted the name "Ben" shortly after Luke and Leia were born, but he was certainly referred to as Obi-Wan for at least the first days or weeks of Luke's life.

In the same movie, Obi-Wan gives Luke Anakin's (second) lightsaber, and says:

> **OBI-WAN**:  *Your father wanted you to have this* when you were old enough, but your uncle wouldn't allow it.

This is a wild misrepresentation of the facts at best, and an incredibly bold lie at worst.  Hearing this, one might be led to believe that Anakin had given the lightsaber to Obi-Wan and said "Give this to my son when he gets older".  In reality, the circumstances under which Obi-Wan took possession of the weapon were much more sinister.  It isn't hard to see why Obi-Wan was less than honest here, because the truth would be something like:

> **OBI-WAN**:  Your dad Force-Choked your mom while she was pregnant with you, and accused me of fooling around with her.  Then he attacked me, so I lopped off both of his legs and one of his arms.  He slid down a hill into some lava, burst into flames, and as he was screaming in the worst agony imaginable, I stole his lightsaber and left him for dead.  The Emperor saved his life, which was nice, and turned him into an evil cyborg, which wasn't nice.  As far as your dad knew, he had killed you and your mom while you were still in the womb.  Your dad never indicated that he wanted you to have his lightsaber, but I guess I'll give it to you anyway, since I already have one.

This is hardly an exhaustive list, so the question is as follows:

#### In the original trilogy, how many times could Obi-Wan be said to have lied to/misled/stretched the truth with Luke?<sup>3</sup>

---

---

<sup>1</sup> From the script of *Return of the Jedi*:

> **LUKE**: Ben! Why didn't you tell me? You told me that Darth Vader betrayed and murdered my father.
>
> **OBI-WAN**: Your father... was seduced by the Dark Side of the Force. He ceased to be the Jedi Anakin Skywalker and "became" Darth Vader. When that happened, the good man who was your father was destroyed. **So, what I told you was true... *from a certain point of view*.**
>
> **LUKE**: A certain point of view?
>
> **OBI-WAN**: Luke, you're going to find that many of the truths we cling to depend greatly on our own point of view.

<sup>2</sup> Even when he is talking *about* Luke, rather than *to* Luke, Obi-Wan occasionally gets things wrong, although he isn't being deliberately misleading.  From the script of *The Empire Strikes Back*:

> **OBI-WAN**:  That boy [Luke] is our last hope.
>
> **YODA**:  No.  There is another [i.e., Leia].

<sup>3</sup> I think the best way to handle the ambiguity Obi-Wan mentions ("What I told you was true...  from a certain point of view") is to assume the worst - if Obi-Wan's statement isn't entirely accurate, it belongs on the list, even if it is possible to justify his decision to stretch the truth or omit some details.  Basically, if Obi-Wan says something and he knows he's not telling "the truth, the whole truth, and nothing but the truth", we can put it on our list.  If, on the other hand, he says something in such a way that all the pertinent facts have been provided and he has no reason to believe that Luke will misunderstand him, he is telling the truth, and it doesn't belong on the list.

Furthermore, I am well aware that many of Obi-Wan's less-than-accurate statements were probably supposed to be true when the scripts were written, and only became untrue due to Lucas' meddling, retcons, and bumbling when he made the prequel trilogy.  This might relieve Obi-Wan of much of the blame, of course, but it doesn't make the things he said any less inaccurate.  Regardless of whether the blame is Lucas' or Obi-Wan's, from an out-of-universe perspective, an untrue statement is untrue.

Comment: How do you know a Jedi is lying? He's opening his mouth.

Comment: Pretty sure Padme referred to Obi-Wan as Ben in Episode 3

Comment: Everything Obi Wan says is a lie. But more importantly, he is infuriating. Notice how he tells Luke *"you're going to find that many of the truths **we cling to** depend greatly on our own point of view"*. "We"!? As if this was something Luke believed for many years out of his own need for "truth" -- this was actually a lie Obi Wan told Luke very recently! Luke didn't know much about his father at all until Obi Wan started misleading him.

Comment: He has always been honest with Luke, *from a certain point of view*

Comment: Out-of-universe: what Obi-Wan tells Luke in ANH could all have been intended as the truth, until ESB got a green light and suddenly got in the way of a cool story hook "I am your father". Although Lucas had prepared outlines for ESB and RotJ from the start, I doubt Lucas or anyone else had Luke's revealed lineage in mind when ANH was being shot. So, poor noble Obi-Wan has to be ret-conned as a liar.

Comment: _"For the greater good"_

Comment: When I watch the original trilogy, I try to forget about specific details from episodes I-II-III. There is more than one inconsistency. Episodes I-II-III didn't do a huge deal of efforts just to make sure that every sentence such as *" I haven't gone by the name Obi-Wan since oh, before you were born."* would be exactly true. At least, it's true that Obi-Wan hasn't been referred as Obi-Wan since he's been in hiding on Tatooine. Whether this began before or after Luke's birth cannot be established from episodes IV-V-VI alone.

Comment: You say "In the original trilogy" but then appear to point at retconning from the second trilogy as evidence of Obi-Wan's deceit. Can you clarify whether works outside the original trilogy should inform answers, and if so which works?

Comment: @ThePopMachine OP meant "less inaccurate"; changes that exonerate Obi-Wan's lies don't make them _less_ of a lie. I've rolled back that revision, since it doesn't make sense anyway, and is the opposite of what OP meant.

Comment: @TylerH:  I read "less accurate".    My bad.  But maybe "more accurate" would be less confusing.  I mean, more unconfusing.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Compromise perhaps "any more or less inaccurate or accurate" to cover all the bases...

Answer (score 206, accepted):

## TL;DR: How do you know Ben Kenobi is lying? Because he's opening his mouth.

50% more untruths than truths in ANH.

56% more untruths than truths in Ep 4+5+6.

## DISCLAIMERS/EXPLANATIONS:

The way I interpreted the question was, **that the intent was to be uncharitable to Obi-Wan**. So that is what I do when scoring.

I **deliberately** pick holes, parse grammar, and do everything else a good lawyer would do in front of judge and jury to show someone as unreliable witness.

## COUNTS:

|  | *IV:ANH* | *V:ESB* | *VI:ROTJ* | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Lies to Luke | 40 | 5 | 11 | 56 |
| Lies to others | 4 | 3 |  | 7 |
| False statements (unknowingly) | 17 | 2.5 | 1.5 | 21 |
| **TOTAL FALSEHOODS:** | **63** | **10.5** | **12.5** | **86** |
| Unknown/Unfalsifiable | 7 | 2 | 2 | 11 |
| Commands or questions | 9 |  |  | 9 |
| **TOTAL UNSCORABLE:** | **16** | **2** | **2** | **20** |
| Truths to Luke | 35.5 | 5 | 9.5 | 50 |
| Truths to others | 4 | 1 |  | 5 |
| **Total Truths:** | **39.5** | **6** | **9.5** | **55** |

## SCOPE COVERED:

Episodes IV, V and VI **ONLY**. Excluded: Clone Wars; EU/Legends, Disney

## Episode IV

- Let's start with the first moment Obi-Wan opens his mouth. NO, not the first words he says to Luke. He starts out with pretending to be a Krayt Dragon instead of a human. In his defense, Luke is unconscious at that moment. But ala CinemaSins, I'm still dinging him. LIE.
- Rest easy, son, you've had a busy day.

  No he didn't. C-3PO drove the landspeeder. Luke just slept in and then passengered around all day. LIE.
- You're fortunate you're still in one piece.

  Not necessarily. We all know from EU that Sand People/Tuskens do NOT just dismember random Force Users - Sharad Hett was made their war leader. Matter of fact, in the *Kenobi* novel, Obi-Wan made "frenemies" with a Tusken leader. MAYBE.
- The Jundland wastes are not to be traveled lightly. Tell me young Luke, what brings you out this far?

  OK, seems to be the truth. Though **he himself is traveling them lightly** apparently, on foot, even, so DING! LIE.
- Obi-Wan Kenobi... Obi-Wan? Now that's a name I haven't heard in a long time... a long time.

  Well, technically speaking, he heard it 1 second ago. DING!
- Oh, he's not dead, not... not yet.

  TRUE!
- Well of course, of course I know him. He's me! I haven't gone by the name Obi-Wan since oh, before you were born.

  As OP noted, false. He was still called Obi-Wan after Luke was born, and only changed his name (according to Miller's "Kenobi" novel) later on Tatooine. LIE.
- Don't seem to remember ever owning a droid. Very interesting...

  LIE. He owned an astromech in his Jedi fighter in ROTS. Having said that, he's also MISLEADING in principle, since he was *implying* that he doesn't know R2-D2. Two dings in one.
- I think we better get indoors.

  TRUE.
- The Sandpeople are easily startled but **they will soon be back** and in greater numbers.

  UNKNOWN. We don't have a baseline to test against (nobody ever checked if they DID come back and in greater numbers).
- Quickly, son... they're on the move.

  See above. We don't know if he's lying - we don't see any Sand People later in that location but we don't see their absence either.
- That's what your uncle told you. He didn't hold with your father's ideals.

  Actually, Owen agreed with the Jedi large-scale, he never opposed Anakin or New Republic when they met. LIE.
- Thought he should have stayed here and not gotten involved

  LIE. **Cleig Lars wasn't married to Shmi yet when Anakin left**, and there's no canon example of them - especially Owen - discussing Anakin leaving. There's also no discussion of Anakin's staying or leaving in later canon to shed more light for Obi-Wan.
- Yes, I was once a Jedi Knight the same as your father.

  Half-true. He was a Jedi Knight but became a Jedi master. Let's be charitable and call it TRUE.
- He was the best star-pilot in the galaxy

  VERY questionable (I suspect Jango, or some other Jedi, may have been better) but plausible since we don't have direct proof to the contrary and his Midichlorians - which was what made him such a great pilot - were off the scale. Let's call it a TRUE just to be nice to old man.
- and a cunning warrior.

  Not really cunning. We see what he does in battle in Episode III, his whole rule about traps is "Let's run towards them and spring them". He never executes a single cunning stratagem, tactically or strategically. LIE.
- I understand you've become quite a good pilot yourself.

  Presumably CORRECT, but never actually shown in canon prior to that point. Luke **let C-3PO drive**. However, in Disney canon, there's zero reason for him to "**understand**" that - how would he know?

  ***NOTE*** As per @WadCheber's comment, a webcomic shows that. I will investigate and update later. For now, changing to TRUE.
- And he was a good friend. Which reminds me...

  I think he may have called him "friend" to Yoda at the end of ROTS. Let's call that one TRUE.
- I have something here for you. Your father wanted you to have this when you were old enough,

  As OP noted, LIE. His father didn't intend to part with it, and most certainly "died" (from a certain point of view) before discussing his estate handling plans with Obi-Wan.
- but your uncle wouldn't allow it.

  I don't think it's true, since Obi-Wan never explicitly discussed giving the lightsaber to Luke with Owen in any canon. but need to check the canon where their talking is discussed later. For now, a LIE until better canon source proves me wrong.
- He feared you might follow old Obi-Wan on some damned-fool idealistic crusade like your father did.

  LIE. Anakin never followed **Obi-Wan**, he followed **Qui-Gon**, as far as Tatooine was concerned. Obi-Wan didn't even want to take him in the first place! And, as noted above, Obi-Wan didn't discuss that with Owen in canon in the first place, to boot.
- Your father's lightsaber. This is the weapon of a Jedi Knight.

  TRUE... or is it? General Grievous wielded four. Sith wielded them. Pre Vizsla wielded one. So... I'm adding on 1/2 LIE, for not correctly stating "weapon of mostly Jedi Knights, but also some others"!
- Not as clumsy or as random as a blaster.

  LIE. Han is far more effective with a blaster than "random" - pretty much 1 shot 1 kill. Leia's even deadlier, having been trained. And Luke was quite clumsy and random with LS at first. It's not the weapon, it's the wielder who determines this.
- An elegant weapon for a more civilized time.

  I wouldn't call Sith Wars and Old Republic times "civilized" and they already had lightsabers. LIE.
- For over a thousand generations the Jedi Knights were the guardians of peace and justice in the Old Republic.

  Half TRUE, half LIE, because it's an extremely large undercount. KOTOR is ~4000 BBY, which means it's **at least** 10-15 thousand generations. Doing things like that gets you major underpayment penalties from IRS for taxes, I can't be any more lenient than IRS.
- Before the dark times, before the Empire.

  TRUE.
- A young Jedi named Darth Vader,

  LIE. His name wasn't Darth Vader when he was a Jedi. And he explicitly stopped being a Jedi by the moment Sidious named him Darth Vader.
- ... who was a pupil of mine until he turned to evil

  Well, he was first Qui-Gon's pupil. I'm tempted to call that TRUE to honor Darth Maul's memory. But, actually, I take that back. **He wasn't Obi-Wan's Padawan "until he turned to evil"** - he was made a Jedi Knight well before then. That stopped the official "pupil" relationship. LIE.
- helped the Empire hunt down and destroy the Jedi Knights.

  TRUE.
- He betrayed and murdered your father.

  LIE!!!! SPOILER:

  > HE DID NOT! HE IS LUKE'S FATHER!
- Now the Jedi are all but extinct.

  Except for a whole bunch found alive in EU. And Kannan in Disney canon. And Ashoka Tano. And Yoda. Granted, Obi-Wan may not have known that, so FALSE, not an intentional lie.
- Vader was seduced by the dark side of the Force.

  Nor really. He was seduced by Palpatine (or should we say Padme? ), **without much care about Dark Side at first**. ROTS novelization is very explicit about that. I'm tempted to call it a lie since Obi-Wan should know better, but let's pretend he didn't read the novelization and is honestly mistaken. FALSE.
- Well, the Force is what gives a Jedi his power.

  TRUE. No, wait, it's Midichlorians! FALSE! OK, OK, fine, I hate Midichlorians too. TRUTH.
- It's an energy field created by all living things.

  Not true! It's not created by Yuuzhan Vong or Ysalamiri, at the very least. OK, let's pretend Obi-Wan isn't a Jedi Master and doesn't know jack about his galaxy... so merely FALSE.
- It surrounds us ...

  TRUE!
- ... and penetrates us.

  LIE. It doesn't directly "penetrate" you, it interacts with Midichlorians in your cells. You can thank the Maker for that scoring, Obi-Wan.
- It binds the galaxy together.

  There is no canon evidence that it's the Force and not gravity beyond Obi-Wan's statement, so I'll call that "untested theory" instead of "false".
- Now, let's see if we can't figure out what you are, my little friend. And where you come from.

  He knows perfectly well what an R2 astromech unit is. LIE. (Also, R2-D2 was not his friend, he was Anakin's, but that's not as important).
- I seem to have found it. (the message)

  TRUE... maybe. Or R2-D2 simply started playing it because it finally <strike>rebooted from the trauma</strike> realized his old friend Obi-Wan was there?
- You **must** learn the ways of the Force if you're to come with me to Alderaan.

  LIE. He can come to the Alderaan **without learning the ways of the Force**. All he needs is a spaceship and a pilot. Or money.
- I **need your help**, Luke.

  **Not really**. Luke wasn't any help on the way to Alderaan, or till pretty much the end of Obi-Wan's life for that matter. LIE.
- She needs your help.

  OK, I'll give him that one. She needed lovestruck Luke to go to insane lengths to free her from Imperial confinement. Granted, Obi-Wan didn't know that, because HE told Luke to stick around and wait for him, NOT to go rescue Leia! So, merely FALSE.

  *Skywalker Family Reunion: Jailbreaking it!*
- I'm getting too old for this sort of thing.

  LIE. Qui-Gon was around his age. Most Jedi were quite successful in their 50's. Yoda kicked &ss at 800 or so.
- That's your uncle talking.

  No, that's Luke talking. He may be agreeing with his uncle, but he's sincere. LIE.
- LUKE: Oh, God, my uncle. **How** am I ever going to explain this? BEN: **Learn about the Force**, Luke.

  LIE. How's learning about the Force gonna help Luke **explain** this to his uncle (who, as per Ben's earlier words, already knows all this anyway!). He's just trying to entice Luke to learn about the Force, under false pretenses (again).

  <sub>Jedi Mind Trick doesn't apply here: JMT on innocent person without need is against Jedi Code & a path to the Dark Side in canon/EU. Explaining to Owen why Luke missed curfew doesn't fall under acceptable exceptions, Obi-Wan knows that.</sub>
- You must do what you feel is right, of course.

  LIE. Luke just told him that what he feels is right is *staying right on Tatooine*, and that's decidedly not what Obi-Wan thinks Luke *must* do.
- They didn't. But we are meant to think they did. These tracks are side by side.

  TRUE.
- Sandpeople always ride single file to hide there numbers.

  According to the EU *Kenobi* novel by Miller, TRUE

  > The members of the raiding party had arrived separately, from two different directions. On their final approach, the four had converged, **running single-file, in the Tusken manner**, until they reached their planned stations behind the northern ridge.
- And these blast points, too accurate for Sandpeople. **Only** Imperial stormtroopers are so precise.

  HA-HA-HA-HA-HA-HA!!!! Sure they are. The only people who are "precise" in that film when shooting are Han and Leia and to some extent Luke. LIE.
- Wait, Luke! It's too dangerous.

  Not really. He can sense in the Force if it's too dangerous (shown repeatedly in canon), and at this time, it's NOT too dangerous as STs are long gone. LIE.
- There's nothing you could have done, Luke, had you been there.

  He could have given the Empire the 2 droids, and pretended he's a simple farm boy who knows nothing.

  Now, that may not have been **effective** (since they burned down the Jawas), but he could have done something, nevertheless. Let's be charitable and call this one TRUE, but he's partly guessing here.
- You'd have been killed, too, and the droids would be in the hands of the Empire.

  TRUE, presumably. But it's a counterfactual so impossible to 100% be sure. See above.
- Mos Eisley Spaceport. You will never find a more wretched hive of scum and villainy. We must be cautious.

  LIE. You can find far worse places in the Galaxy, apparently, according to canon. Jabba's palace, for one, so no need to go too far either geographically or by canon.
- You don't need to see his identification.

  OK, that wasn't lying to **Luke**, but he's still LYING hiz zhopa off.

  *And yes I just used Ender's Game slang in Star Wars question, for those keeping score.*
- These are not the droids your looking for.

  Ditto. LIE.
- He can go about his business.

  TRUE! Looks like he doesn't always lie even to Stormtroopers!
- Move along.

  It's a COMMAND.
- The Force can have a strong influence on the weak-minded.

  TRUE
- You will find it a powerful ally.

  TRUE. Except when JMT Jabba the Hutt :)
- Well, most of the best freighter pilots can be found here.

  Unknown but likely FALSE. Galaxy Far Far Away has millions of worlds, the best pilots are surely diffused through them and don't ALL hang out on Tatooine.
- Only watch your step. This place can be **a little rough**.

  Actually, it's full of murder, so it's **a LOT MORE than "a little" rough**. LIE!
- This little one isn't worth the effort.

  Again, not lying *to Luke*. But lying nonetheless. Any idea how much Anakin Skywalker's son's head is worth to the Imperials?
- Come let me buy you something...

  COMMAND.
- This is Chewbacca. He's first-mate on a ship that might suit our needs.

  I don't recall ever in canon reading that Chewie's position was "first mate". Co-pilot? Yes. FALSE.
- Yes, indeed. If it's a fast ship.

  Starts out telling truth to Han. Promising!
- Should I have? (known about Falcon)

  Can't score, it's a question. N/A
- Only passengers. Myself, the boy, two droids ...

  TRUE
- ... **and no questions asked**.

  He allowed Han to ask plenty of questions later! ... like... 1 second later! LIE.

  > HAN: What is it? Some kind of local trouble?
- Let's just say we'd like to avoid any Imperial entanglements.

  TRUE.
- We haven't that much with us. But we could pay you two thousand now, plus fifteen when we reach Alderaan.

  Hard to score. Presumably, he didn't intend to lie and simply made a mistake. BUT!!! Alderaanian "fifteen" never did happen! So FALSE!
- Ninety-four.

  N/A. He's just repeating Han's words.
- You'll **have to** sell your speeder.

  Not really, he doesn't **HAVE to**. Ben can Jedi-mind-trick someone into giving him 2000. Or win a game of chance like Qui-Gon did before. LIE.
- It will be enough. (about speeder's selling price)

  TRUE. It was enough.
- If the ship's as fast as he's boasting, we ought to do well.

  FALSE. The ship's speed is clearly irrelevant, as the Empire is **waiting at their destination**. Well he didn't know that, so not a lie, just a mistake.
- How long before you can make the jump to light speed?

  A question, so not a lie. I'm tempted to ding him since he's an experienced pilot himself and ought to know! N/A.
- I felt a great disturbance in the Force... as if millions of voices suddenly cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced.

  TRUE
- I fear something terrible has happened.

  LIE! He didn't "fear". Jedi don't "fear", it leads to Dark Side!
- You'd better get on with your exercises.

  A command, so N/A
- Remember, a Jedi can feel the Force flowing through him.

  TRUE, I suppose. That's how he and other Jedi are described when doing Forcey things elsewhere in canon.
- Partially (re: "You mean it controls your actions?").

  Actually, the Force doesn't **control** anyone's actions that we observe in canon, at all. Let's be charitable and call it FALSE, he may not have known the Force intricacies, not being a Sith.
- But it also obeys your commands.

  TRUE
- I suggest you try it again, Luke.

  Another command. N/A
- This time, let go your conscious self and **act on instinct**.

  LIE! Jedi don't rely on "**instinct**", which is something wholly different than "flowing with the Force".
- Your eyes can deceive you. Don't trust them.

  TRUE. You see a Force Ghost of Sebastian Shaw, and the next moment, he turns into Hayden Christiansen. Embarrassing, that is.
- Stretch out with your feelings.

  TRUE. Other Jedi describe it that way too in canon
- You see, you can do it.

  TRUE, Captain Obvious! Of course he can, he just did it!
- In my experience, there's no such thing as luck.

  Seriously? How do you describe Han's Sabbac play then? He's not a Jedi! FALSE! Actually, more than that - it's a LIE: Anakin's landing of the ship in ROTS is very explicitly explained as having elements of "luck"! And Obi-Wan was there:

  > And at the same time, he draws power from the Force. He gathers perception, **and luck**, and sucks into himself the instinctive, preconscious what-will-happen-in-the-next-ten-seconds intuition that has always been the core of his talent.

  For that matter, they didn't even need Anakin's luck! Jar-Jar's luck will suffice in *The Phantom Menace*:

  > But a quick glance back revealed that **they were lucky for a different reason than they thought**. The open sea killer was caught in the jaws of a creature so huge that it dwarfed even the beast it was eating. A long, eel-like hunter with clawed forelegs, rear fins, and a wicked pair of jaws was crunching the sea killer into tiny bits and swallowing it down eagerly.

  A LIE!
- That's good. You have taken your first step into a larger world.

  MISLEADING. Luke "took his first step into a larger world" when he first stepped outside Lars homestead years ago. Or got onto Falcon hours ago to leave Tatooine.
- Destroyed... by the Empire!

  TRUE.
- It's an Imperial fighter.

  TRUE
- No. It's a short range fighter.

  TRUE. Incidentally, how the hell does HE know? He wasn't keeping up to date on latest Imperial military tech in his cave on Tatooine, right? So, accidental truth.
- It'd be as well to let it go.

  TRUE. If they did, they wouldn't have ended up Tarkin's guests.
- It's too far out of range.

  FALSE! He knows nothing about Millennium's souped-up systems and Han proves him wrong when he outruns TIEs later.
- A fighter **that size** couldn't get this deep into space on its own.

  FALSE! TIE/advanced was about the same size and had a hyperdrive.

  In Obi-Wan's defense, he had earlier complained in canon about not having hyperdrive and needing a hyperdrive ring on Jedi fighters, so he's being genuine here, not lying.
- That's no moon! It's a space station.

  FALSE! A space station implies **stationary** position, and Death Star is by no means stationary.

  It also isn't in orbit, which is a most common context implied by that phrase according to Wikipedia definition.
- You **can't** win.

  FALSE. Yes he can. Later in canon, Luke successfully wins over tractor beams, by blowing up stuff that clutters tractor beam and confuses it.
- But there are alternatives to fighting.

  TRUE, duh
- Leave that to me! (re: tractor beam)

  TRUE
- Who's the more foolish... the fool or the fool who follows him?

  Too fortune-cookie to be falsifiable. N/A
- Plug in. He should be able to interpret the entire Imperial computer network.

  TRUE. Up to and including reading the bloody map that won't show up for 30 years till Episode VII!!!
- I don't think you boys can help.

  He truly doesn't think so, so TRUE
- I must go alone.

  I'll be lenient and call that TRUE, because he needed Jedi Stealth to get by stormtroopers and Hand and Luke would have effed that stealth up.
- Be patient, Luke. Stay and watch over the droids.

  A command, so N/A. On the other hand... if Luke was patient and stayed, he'd never have freed Leia, so FALSE!
- They must be delivered safely or other star systems will suffer the same fate as Alderaan.

  TRUE.
- Your destiny lies along a different path than mine.

  Actually... he and his Jedi will be betrayed by his student Kylo Ren. Same path! FALSE!!!!
- The Force will be with you... always!

  FALSE! It won't be with him when he's surrounded by Ysalamiri . Or when he fights Clone "Luuke".

  Even in Disney canon, clearly it wasn't with him when Ben "Whiny" destroyed his Jedi Academy.
- Only a master of evil, Darth.

  His name isn't Darth (and nobody refers to him that way), so LIE!
- You can't win, Darth.

  LIE! Sure he can. Short term, he wins by killing Kenobi. Long term, he wins by killing the Emperor, which Yoda and OB1 couldn't do. Darth Vader FTW!
- If you strike me down, I shall become more powerful than you can possibly imagine.

  I dunno, he can imagine quite a bit.... :)

  Seriously, LIE. He doesn't become powerful in any meaningful sense of the word.

  Besides, Darth Vader, being a Sith, surely knows about past Sith Lords who successfully escaped death, and came back to life later during KOTOR times.
- Run, Luke! Run!

  A command, so N/A
- Luke, the Force will be with you.

  TRUE, in general. But we established that it won't be with him "Always", so 1/2 TRUE, 1/2 FALSE.
- Use the Force, Luke.

  A command, so N/A
- Let go, Luke.

  A command, so N/A
- Luke, trust me.

  As we see from the above summary... NO!!! LIE!!! He can't be trusted!
- Remember, the Force will be with you... **always**.

  As we already established, A LIE!

---

### Episode V

- Luke... Luke.... You will go to the Dagobah system.

  TRUE
- There you will learn from Yoda,

  TRUE ultimately, but remember, Yoda barely agreed to teach him and almost rejected him. So, FALSE as well, from a certain point of view
- the Jedi Master who instructed me.

  A LIE in the big picture. He was mostly taught by Qui-Gon.

  However, from a certain point of view, all Younglings were taught by Yoda as we see in "Lost a planet, Obi-Wan has" scene from AotC, so it's at least partially true.
- He will learn patience.

  FALSE. No he won't. He will rush off to confront Vader on Bespin and nearly ruin everything.
- Was I any different when you taught me?

  A LIE. As we established, he was taught by Qui-Gon. And when we see him as Padawan, he's quite the opposite, Qui-Gon chastises him for NOT living in the moment and using the Living Force (as opposed to Dead Force he was wielding)
- YODA: You are reckless!
  BEN: So was I, if you'll remember.

  See above. He wasn't ever reckless, he was the MORE cautious out of Qui-Gon and himself; OR out of Anakin and himself. LIE.
- LUKE: But Han and Leia will die if I don't {go}.
  BEN'S VOICE: You don't know that.

  TRUE. He doesn't know.
- Even Yoda cannot see their fate.

  TRUE. Yoda couldn't see a Sith Master 2 feet away from him for years. Weak, his Oracle-fu, is.
- But you cannot control it {the Force}.  This is a dangerous time for you, when you will be tempted by the dark side of the Force.

  LIE.

  - He will be tempted by the Dark side of the Force **all his life**, not just this time. Starting earlier (Dark Side Cave on Dagobah), then at Jabba's palace, then on Death Star 2, then in a bunch of places in EU/Legends, too numerous to count
  - Moreover, specifically on Bespin, he was **NOT** really tempted by the Dark Side, at least in comparison to other times.
- It is you and your abilities the Emperor wants. That is why your friends are made to suffer.

  True? But wait. His friends are actually made to suffer because **Vader** wants Luke and his abilities (to kill the Emperor and rule the galaxy together). And the Emperor wasn't the one torturing or even ordering torture. FALSE!
- Luke, I don't want to lose you to the Emperor the way I lost Vader.

  True? Except he lost Anakin, he never had Vader. **Technically FALSE**. Half each.
- Patience!

  A command. N/A
- If you choose to face Vader, you will do it alone.

  FALSE. Lando helped him to face Vader, by freeing his friends so they aren't hostages to Vader anymore.
- I cannot interfere.

  LIE. Canon Post-sequel-Disney-trilogy: Yoda blasted lightning as Force-Ghost
- Luke, don't give in to hate -

  Command. N/A
- that leads to the dark side.

  TRUE
- That boy is our last hope.

  LIE!!! "No. There is another." - *Yoda*, less than a second later.

---

### Episode VI

- Yoda will always be with you.

  LIE. He will appear once in a while as a Force Ghost in EU and some Disney BS, but that doesn't qualify as "always".
- Your father was seduced by the dark side of the Force.

  LIE. As noted in Episode VI lies, he was seduced by Sidious, NOT by Dark Side (which in itself held little attraction to him based on Episode III novelization)
- He ceased to be Anakin Skywalker and became Darth Vader.

  TRUE. He said so himself.
- When that happened, the good man who was your father was destroyed.

  LIE. He was not a "good man" even before that. He was a creepy pervert, who murdered Tusken kids by the village, married Padme despite knowing it was wrong.
- So what I have told you was true… from a certain point of view.

  LIE. It wasn't true! It was just twisting the facts.
- Luke, you’re going to find that many of the truths we cling to depend greatly on our own point of view.

  Hard to say, but given my own (somewhat extensive knowledge) of EU/Legends and Disney canon, I don't think Luke ever finds "**many**" truths he used to cling to to be "depends" category.

  So I'm rating this 1/2 true, 1/2 false.
- Anakin was a good friend.

  TRUE.
- When I first knew him, your father was already a great pilot.

  TRUE
- But I was amazed how strongly the Force was with him.

  TRUE.
- I took it upon myself to train him as a Jedi.

  LIE. Qui-Gon took it upon himself. Obi-Wan merely did what both Qui-Gon and the Jedi Council told him to do.
- I thought that I could instruct him just as well as Yoda. I was wrong.

  Yoda didn't instruct anyone except 3 year old Padawans since Dooku (who was his last above-3-YO padawan). Obi-Wan didn't witness Dooku stuff. LIE.
- He’s more machine now than man.

  LIE. He has less than 1/2 machine by volume.
- Twisted and evil.

  OK, gotta agree on that one.
- You **cannot** escape your destiny.

  LIE. He CAN very easily escape his destiny, slink off to some remote planet and obiwan the rest of his life there. Or slink off to Dagobah and hide out in Yoda's cave.
- You **must** face Darth Vader again.

  LIE. It's not a "must", it's a "should" or "ought". See above. He has an option of running away.
- Then the Emperor has already won. You were our only hope.

  LIE. Leia was another
- The other he spoke of is your twin sister.

  TRUE. I'm tempted to ding 1/2 a lie, because **he could have told him prior to two films of unresolved sexual tension and snogging**.
- Hmm. To protect you both from the Emperor, you were hidden from your father when you were born.

  TRUE
- The Emperor knew, as I did, if Anakin were to have any offspring, they would be a threat to him.

  LIE. There is absolutely no canon information that at the time of birth, the Emperor had any *specific* thoughts about Anakin's kids. He probably had those thoughts, but **neither Obi-Wan nor us, the canon consumers, know of them**.
- That is the reason why your sister remains safely anonymous.

  TRUE, I suppose. Thought a good lawyer could twist the "safely" into a lie in front of a jury by taking it out of context.
- Your insight serves you well. Bury your feelings deep down, Luke. They do you credit. But they could be made to serve the Emperor.

  TRUE.

Comment: typically a "generation" is considered to be ~20 years (the rough age when young adults start giving birth to the "next generation", so 1,000 generations is therefore about 20,000 years. Since the Old Republic *started* ~25,000 BBY and ended ~1000 BBY I think his statement is within reasonable margin of error.

Comment: Obi-Wan's fighter did have an astromech droid. It even had a name.

Comment: Did someone just nuke this whole comment thread? If someone posted anything genuinely worth editing in (like Obi-Wan's droid) in the last 24 hours, please re-post.

Comment: @wad - one edit too many. Luke's clone's name was "Luuke", that was how all clone names in Thrawn Trilogy were constructed

Comment: Re:  edits - that's my bad, I haven't read the books.  Re:  comments - Someone in chat complained about the length of the comments and said they flagged the post for trimming.  Unfortunately, it looks like the good stuff was deleted with the bad.

Comment: I admire your dedication to this topic. We should point out the chronological discrepancies of the creation of the films however. A lot of the comments are said to be false based on evidence from Episode 1-3 (the 4th, 5th, and 6th movies) which are during the time period prefacing the original movies. If future directors/writers/actors didn't adhere to the original information, you cannot declare Obi-Wan a liar because they MADE him a liar. But still, he's a liar for other reasons :P

Comment: @ColdLogic - I addressed that in the final footnote on my question.  I thought it would make things easier if we ignored the issue of  who is responsible for the lie, out of universe, and only focus on the lie itself.

Comment: @WadCheber - I saved (and mostly addressed) the good stuff till ~12 hours ago. Not after.

Comment: *'"Luke, I don't want to lose you to the Emperor the way I lost Vader." TRUE?? Except he lost Anakin, he never had Vader. Technically FALSE.* You can't have it both ways: either Anakin and Vader are the same person, so this statement is true, or Anakin and Vader are different people, so Ben's famous "from a certain point of view" statements are true.

Comment: @Martha - They are the same person, but the names were very chronologically different. He wasn't called Vader at the time the loss happened'

Comment: When you tell someone the story of how your parents met, do you say "Well, Dave was working at Acme Rockets...", or do you say "Well, Dad was working at Acme Rockets..."? I'm willing to bet it's the latter, even though at the time the story happens, "Dad" was clearly not what he was called.

Comment: Okay, hats off for the undertaking!  I do, however, have one I'd like to challenge.  "This is the weapon of a Jedi Knight."  First off, it would be a totally reasonable interpretation to treat this as "The Jedi Knight all use this kind of weapon as their weapon."  Second, this individual lightsaber *was* the weapon of a Jedi Knight, before he relinquished it for a Sith red one.  I think this statement has to be treated as true.

Comment: @CortAmmon - I don't disagree. However, the whole question was ALL about unreasonable interpretations! :)

Comment: Obi-Wan didn't know about the Yuuzhan Vong or Ysaalmiri (they were both discovered after the movies, and only in Legends), so I don't think it's fair to classify "the force is an energy field created by all living things" as a lie.

Comment: "You cannot escape your destiny. " Kinda phylosophical to judge about this. How you could even know?

Comment: + You seem to begin getting inconsistent. "but neither Obi-Wan nor us, the canon consumers, know of them." you judge something as a lie if he says unkowingly untruth (thats ok by OP). But now you claim something is a lie, just because we have no evidence about he knew to that time that thats true? I mean out of universe the character definetly wasn't designed to be an illusionist/lier. So now assuming when ever we cant confirm that obi wan said INTENTIONALLY the truth, assuming he intended to lie is finally a little bit too much.

Comment: You don't like Obiwan too much, right?

Comment: @MaëlNison - I'm like a lawyer. On this question, I'm paid not to like him

Comment: How about a tally of the truths, falsehoods, and in-betweens to sum everything up neatly?

Comment: @WadCheber - was gonna, till got all kinds of discouraged on Meta yesterday.

Comment: @WadCheber You still get my vote as #1 answer :P

Comment: "the whole question was ALL about unreasonable interpretations" -- that makes your answer make a whooooooole lot more sense. It would make a good disclaimer at the top so that everyone is aware you're being intentionally uncharitable in your interpretations.

Comment: Also, what happened on Meta?

Comment: I'd classify "plus fifteen when we reach Alderaan" as true. When making such an agreement it is implied that the final payment is only paid if they successfully do reach Alderaan. I am convinced that if they had reached Alderaan in one piece, then Obi-Wan would have arranged for Han to receive payment as agreed.

Comment: @KyleStrand - good idea! Edited that in.Thanks! As for Meta, long story. Someone was attacking me in a rather rude way, personally. Neither moderators nor anyone except *one* user saw fit to note that the personal attacks were not how one should conduct themselves on the site; leaving alone their accuracy. As I have announced on Meta, I'm leaving the site, this answer being part of my swan song.

Comment: @WadCheber - tally done. Also narrowed down precisely lies from unintended falsehoods from unscorable things.

Comment: Obi-Wan Kenobi... Obi-Wan? Now that's a name I haven't heard in a long time... a long time.
Well, technically speaking, he heard it 1 second ago. DING!
Its not wrong but thats just mean. 
Yoda will always be with you.
LIE. He will appear once in a while as a Force Ghost in EU, but that doesn't qualify as "always". I would say this is not defined. Since he is now part of the force he can be everywhere without necessarily manifesting as a ghost.

Comment: He’s more machine now than man.
LIE. He has less than 1/2 machine by volume. I would also like to challenge that based on 2 things: 1. he lost 2 legs a hand and probably his lungs + everything that got burned away or had to be romved/replaced by surgery. 2. he has a lot of machinery added so even with more than half his body left he might be mor machine

Comment: @Eumel - by volume, 3 limbs are far smaller than a body+head (I remember that from some investigation I did). His breathing is all in a mask+suit which don't add that much volume by the looks of it

Comment: It's one thing to purposely take the worst possible interpretation, just for gits and shiggles; it's another thing to count honest mistakes/misstatements as lies. No matter how "guilty unless proven innocent" you're being, a lie is a thing of intent: if you believe what you're saying is true, then no matter what the circumstances, **it's not a lie**. As a result, I can't get more than a quarter of the way through this answer without giving up in disgust.

Comment: @DVK: I'm sorry, I truly did not intend to offend you. I think this answer is incorrect, and frustratingly so (since you obviously spent a *lot* of time on it), but I definitely don't want to jump on any "let's dump on DVK" bandwagon (if such a thing exists).

Comment: @Martha - I can definitely understand the frustraion with seeing content that seems incorrect to you (even though I obviously disagree with your assessment of correctness of my answer :). But expressing it in a bit more constructive way would help to reduce the bandwagon (whose existence is the reason I'm leaving the site).

Comment: @Martha - having said that, have you actually seen the *updated* version of my answer? I have explicitly reclassified a large portion of falsehoods from LIE to FALSE, when there was clear proof of  lack of knowledge by OB1 that what he said was actually false (and I openly admitted that I did a bit of slipshod job of labelling on the original version in the answer itself - mostly, because I was still working on it; I fully intended to fix it asap;but got discouraged continuing after being called "petulant, whiny, entitled troll" in public with *zero reaction* from anyone including moderators)

Comment: "Obi-Wan Kenobi... Obi-Wan? Now that's a name I haven't heard in a long time... a long time." Well, technically speaking, he heard it 1 second ago. -- That is the proper use of the statement. If you want to get nit-picky (clearly you do), the full statement implied is "Now that's a name I haven't heard in a long time, _previous to you just saying it to me_. If you leave out the implication, it could never, ever be true, could it?

Comment: He does have to sell his speeder - from Obi Wan's point of view.  Obi Wan isn't going to unethically JMT a random rich dude to get the money to pay off Cap Solo.

Comment: The irony is that George Lucas never set out to make Obi-Wan such a lying bastard. It's just George's retconning over the years that turned him into one.

Comment: +1 This is the greatest answer in all of the Stack Exchange network. Thank you

Comment: If the Republic persisted about 25,000 years, which seems to be the case, that's pretty much exactly 1000 generations. Have no idea where you get 10 to 15 thousand generations.

Comment: Is this the biggest answer on the SE Network?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal - (1) No. There are several answer which are longer; including one of mine. (2) However, this seems weirdly difficult to measure due to [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297954/why-is-lenbody-incorrect-on-answers-in-data-se) with [the Data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/679663/top-10-longest-answers)

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To But anyway, this is one of the greatest answers I have seen on the StackExchange network. Tremendous job man! :)

Comment: @PrittBalagopal - thank you! You may appreciate [this one as well](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112251/which-predictions-of-the-force-awakens-darths-droids-bingo-were-correct/112253#112253) which is even longer :) (self-plug)

Comment: Ugh, this answer sucks. So many logical flaws, -1

Comment: For the droids I don't think he owned an astromech droid. As far as it seemed form the clone wars either the republic or the order owned the droids and just assigned them to the jedi in question as they didn't "own" them (as owning them would be some sort of attachment though). At least my impression there. so could be that he told the truth there that he didn't remember OWNIG an astromech droid

Comment: "You cannot escape your destiny.

LIE. He CAN very easily escape his destiny, slink off to some remote planet and obiwan the rest of his life there. Or slink off to Dagobah and hide out in Yoda's cave." -- sorry, by the literal definition of the word "destiny", this is completely true: if Luke *did* slink off and hide out on Dagobah, then that would have been his destiny, so he wouldn't have escaped it...

Answer (score 63):

TL;DR: Analyzing *A New Hope* only (because I don't have time for more), and using the same quotes as DVK posted, I counted 11 definite lies, 2 arguable statements, 7 statements to which no truth value can be assigned (questions or commands), and 75 statements that are definitely not lies - they may be opinions, even incorrect opinions (though we don't know of too many of those), but they're not counterfactual or misleading. Naturally, all numbers are approximate, because where do you draw the line between one statement and the next?, but this means Obi-Wan lies in ANH no more than 15% of the time.

---

- [pretending to be a Krayt Dragon]

  Seriously?
- "Rest easy, son, you've had a busy day."

  True.
- "You're fortunate you're still in one piece."

  True. ("In one piece" is an idiom meaning "not injured". It is not generally used literally.)
- "The Jundland wastes are not to be traveled lightly."

  Demonstrably true.
- "Tell me young Luke, what brings you out this far?"

  No truth value can be assigned.
- "Obi-Wan Kenobi... Obi-Wan? Now that's a name I haven't heard in a long time... a long time."

  True: 20 years is generally considered a long time.
- "Oh, he's not dead, not... not yet."

  True.
- "Well of course, of course I know him. He's me! I haven't gone by the name Obi-Wan since oh, before you were born."

  Per the OP's stipulations, this is a lie.
- "Don't seem to remember ever owning a droid. Very interesting..."

  If we take this as implying that he doesn't know R2-D2, then this is a lie. If we take this as saying "Hm, I wonder why R2 is pretending to be my property when he knows very well that he isn't", well, it's certainly not a lie.
- "I think we better get indoors. The Sandpeople are easily startled but they will soon be back and in greater numbers."

  True.
- "Quickly, son... they're on the move."

  As far as we know, true.
- "That's what your uncle told you. He didn't hold with your father's ideals."

  I think we don't actually know enough about Owen's opinions to evaluate this statement. However, insofar as Obi-Wan is implying that Owen didn't tell Luke about his father because there was a disagreement between the brothers, that's getting into serious "from a certain point of view" territory. I'd have to call this a borderline lie from Obi-Wan.
- "Thought he should have stayed here and not gotten involved."

  Anakin had already left Tatooine and gotten involved before Owen's dad entered the picture, so there is no way to interpret this as true; this is Obi-Wan further spinning his tale about the disagreeing brothers. LIE.
- "Yes, I was once a Jedi Knight the same as your father."

  True. ("Jedi Knight" is the general term as well as a particular rank. All Jedi Masters are Jedi Knights; not all Jedi Knights are Jedi Masters.)
- "He was the best star-pilot in the galaxy"

  Opinion stated as fact is still opinion: as far as we know, Obi-Wan believed this to be true, so it's not a lie.
- "and a cunning warrior."

  Again, a truly-held opinion is not a lie.
- "I understand you've become quite a good pilot yourself."

  True.
- "And he was a good friend. Which reminds me..."

  True.
- "I have something here for you. Your father wanted you to have this when you were old enough,"

  Lie.
- "but your uncle wouldn't allow it."

  The films don't give us any information about this subject. I think we can classify it as part of the previous lie, though.
- "He feared you might follow old Obi-Wan on some damned-fool idealistic crusade like your father did."

  Insofar as this is still assigning motivations to Owen which we don't know him to have, I think this is a continuation of the lying.
- "Your father's lightsaber. This is the weapon of a Jedi Knight."

  True. (Other people also using lightsabers doesn't mean they're not Jedi weapons. Americans and Australians speaking English doesn't mean we can't call English the language of the British Isles.)
- "Not as clumsy or as random as a blaster."

  Opinion.
- "An elegant weapon for a more civilized time."

  Opinion.
- "For over a thousand generations the Jedi Knights were the guardians of peace and justice in the Old Republic."

  True. ("Over a thousand generations" includes *all* numbers greater than one thousand, not just the ones DVK likes.)
- "Before the dark times, before the Empire."

  True.
- "A young Jedi named Darth Vader, who was a pupil of mine until he turned to evil, helped the Empire hunt down and destroy the Jedi Knights."

  Oy. Certain point of view, indeed. Other than the name, this is all true statements, and even the name is true enough if we don't quibble about the timing... This is a preamble to the biggest lie Obi-Wan tells, but is not, in itself, a lie.
- "He betrayed and murdered your father."

  As DVK said, SPOILER:

  > HE DID NOT! HE IS LUKE'S FATHER!
- "Now the Jedi are all but extinct."

  As far as Obi-Wan knows, it's down to him and Yoda, so perfectly true.
- "Vader was seduced by the dark side of the Force."

  True.
- "Well, the Force is what gives a Jedi his power."

  True.
- "It's an energy field created by all living things. It surrounds us and penetrates us."

  True. Obi-Wan is perhaps simplifying a bit, but that's a perfectly valid technique when you're explaining a brand-new concept.
- "It binds the galaxy together."

  No idea what Obi-Wan means here, but at worst, it's a statement of opinion.
- "Now, let's see if we can't figure out what you are, my little friend. And where you come from."

  As before, if we interpret this as implying that he doesn't know R2, then it's a lie. But in actual fact, Ben doesn't know what R2-D2 is *currently* - spy? courier? innocent droid? - nor where he came from.
- "I seem to have found it." (the message)

  True.
- "You must learn the ways of the Force if you're to come with me to Alderaan."

  Lie. Sorta. Ben sincerely believes that Luke needs to learn the ways of the Force, but he's putting in the bit about Alderaan to sweeten the pot, not because it's actually true.
- "I need your help, Luke."

  True: once Obi-Wan decided to re-join the fray, he knew he needed all the help he could get.
- "She needs your help."

  More sweetening of the pot, but true enough when you come right down to it.
- "I'm getting too old for this sort of thing."

  Opinion.
- "That's your uncle talking."

  True: Luke was saying "it's not my problem" because that's what he had been taught all his life. By his uncle.
- LUKE: "Oh, God, my uncle. How am I ever going to explain this?" BEN: "Learn about the Force, Luke."

  Nonsequitur, but true enough. Not a lie, certainly.
- "You must do what you feel is right, of course."

  This is Ben saying what he thinks Luke needs to hear, so it's a lie... from a certain point of view.
- "They didn't. But we are meant to think they did. These tracks are side by side."

  True.
- "Sandpeople always ride single file to hide their numbers."

  True, or at worst, opinion.
- "And these blast points, too accurate for Sandpeople. Only Imperial stormtroopers are so precise."

  I know it's fashionable to laugh at this line, but as one of the best answers on this site points out, Stormtroopers are incredibly precise *when they're **allowed** to be*.
- "Wait, Luke! It's too dangerous."

  Opinion.
- "There's nothing you could have done, Luke, had you been there."

  True, or at least well-informed opinion.
- "You'd have been killed, too, and the droids would be in the hands of the Empire."

  True, or at least well-informed opinion.
- "Mos Eisley Spaceport. You will never find a more wretched hive of scum and villainy. We must be cautious."

  Opinion, at worst.
- "You don't need to see his identification."

  Lie. :)
- "These are not the droids your looking for."

  More lies. :)
- "He can go about his business. Move along."

  The minute the stormtrooper says it, it becomes true. Trying to figure out whether it's true before that is making my head hurt.
- "The Force can have a strong influence on the weak-minded. You will find it a powerful ally."

  Quite true.
- "Well, most of the best freighter pilots can be found here."

  Why Obi-Wan knows this, we don't know, but have no reason to think he's lying. (He did spend some time on Coruscant being a glorified police officer, so he probably learned a thing or two about identifying what's what and who's who in the criminal world.)
- "Only watch your step. This place can be a little rough."

  Understatement, but not a lie.
- "This little one isn't worth the effort."

  Since Obi-Wan clearly intends to protect Luke at all costs, all that bar patron would gain from said effort would be a fatal lightsaber wound or two. Ben is perhaps making assumptions about how high the guy values his own life, but he's not lying.
- "Come, let me buy you something..."

  True, as far as we can see.
- "This is Chewbacca. He's first mate on a ship that might suit our needs."

  True.
- "Yes, indeed. If it's a fast ship."

  True.
- "Should I have?" (heard about Falcon)

  No truth value can be assigned.
- "Only passengers. Myself, the boy, two droids, and no questions asked."

  True.
- "Let's just say we'd like to avoid any Imperial entanglements."

  True.
- "We haven't that much with us. But we could pay you two thousand now, plus fifteen when we reach Alderaan."

  He's playing fast and loose with someone else's money, but he's not lying: he has no intention to stiff Han, as far as we know.
- "Ninety-four."

  Repeating what was said; no truth value can be assigned.
- "You'll have to sell your speeder."

  True. (The possibility of cheating/stealing the money some other way doesn't mean he was lying about selling the speeder.)
- "It will be enough." (about speeder's selling price)

  True.
- "If the ship's as fast as he's boasting, we ought to do well."

  True.
- "How long before you can make the jump to light speed?"

  No truth value can be assigned.
- "I felt a great disturbance in the Force... as if millions of voices suddenly cried out in terror and were silenced."

  True.
- "I fear something terrible has happened."

  True.
- "You'd better get on with your exercises."

  No truth value can be assigned.
- "Remember, a Jedi can feel the Force flowing through him."

  True.
- LUKE: "You mean it controls your actions?" Ben: "Partially. But it also obeys your commands."

  True, or at least we have no reason to think otherwise.
- "I suggest you try it again, Luke. This time, let go your conscious self and act on instinct. Your eyes can deceive you. Don't trust them. Stretch out with your feelings."

  This is all either true or a statement of opinion; none of it is intended to mislead anyone.
- "You see, you can do it."

  True, since he just did.
- "In my experience, there's no such thing as luck."

  Opinion. It's even phrased as such.
- "That's good. You have taken your first step into a larger world."

  True.
- "Destroyed... by the Empire!"

  Jumping to conclusions, perhaps, but not a lie.
- "It's an Imperial fighter."

  True.
- "No. It's a short range fighter."

  True.
- "It'd be as well to let it go. It's too far out of range. A fighter that size couldn't get this deep into space on its own."

  True, as far as Obi-Wan knows.
- "That's no moon! It's a space station."

  True: he doesn't know the official terminology, but the Death Star certainly isn't a moon, but a man-made construct.
- "You can't win."

  True: in a firefight between the Falcon and the Death Star, there can only be one possible winner, and it's not the Falcon.
- "But there are alternatives to fighting."

  True.
- "Leave that to me!" (re: tractor beam)

  True.
- "Who's the more foolish... the fool or the fool who follows him?"

  Opinion, I guess. Definitely not a lie, in any case.
- "Plug in. He should be able to interpret the entire Imperial computer network."

  True.
- "I don't think you boys can help. I must go alone."

  Opinion and/or true.
- "Be patient, Luke. Stay and watch over the droids."

  No truth value can be assigned.
- "They must be delivered safely or other star systems will suffer the same fate as Alderaan."

  True.
- "Your destiny lies along a different path than mine."

  Demonstrably true.
- "The Force will be with you... always!"

  Kind of a tautology, given that the Force is always with everyone, but still: not a lie.
- "Only a master of evil, Darth."

  Quite true: Anakin never reached Jedi Master status, but Darth Vader has certainly achieved the Sith equivalent of that rank.
- "You can't win, Darth."

  Opinion stated as fact, maybe. Not a lie, in any case.
- "If you strike me down, I shall become more powerful than you can possibly imagine."

  Regardless of the truth value of this statement, Obi-Wan clearly believes it strongly enough to sacrifice his life to it. So about as not-a-lie as is humanly possible.
- "Run, Luke! Run!"

  No truth value can be assigned.
- "Luke, the Force will be with you."

  Opinion, hope, or truth, but not a lie.
- "Use the Force, Luke. Let go, Luke. Luke, trust me."

  No truth value can be assigned.
- "Remember, the Force will be with you... always."

  A tautology maybe, but not a lie.

Comment: Fantastic reasoned answer without snide comments and glibness +1

Comment: Luke is unconscious when Obi-Wan rescues him from the Sand People, so Obi-Wan was definitely *not* lying/stretching the truth/etc. **with Luke** by allegedly impersonating a Krayt Dragon.

Comment: I'm not sure Obiwan really did lied when he said that Dark Vador had killed Luke's father. It's certainly a way to see what happened.

Comment: @MaëlNison - please re-read the specific instructions in the question. This wasn't meant to be objective and fair evaluation of Obi-Wans statements with "innocent until proven guilty" basis. AT ALL.

Answer (score 19):

I'm entirely dissatisfied with the state of the existing answers, so here are the times someone using the '[reasonable person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reasonable_person)' test would consider Obi-Wan lying/stretching the truth while talking to Luke, in order of the most outright lie/misdirection to the smallest (spoiler alert: there aren't many):

**1. When Obi-Wan said that Darth Vader betrayed and murdered Luke's father.**

(Darth Vader *is* Luke's father, previously known as Anakin Skywalker)

**2. When Obi-Wan said that Luke's father wanted Luke to have his old lightsaber.**

(Anakin never referenced or discussed children of his own--real or desired--while talking to Obi-Wan, though it is likely true that, had Anakin maintained custody of his offspring, he would have helped them construct a lightsaber eventually)

**3. When Obi-Wan mentions Luke's uncle Owen as the reason for Luke not receiving the lightsaber sooner and as a person who disagreed with Anakin's involvement in the Clone Wars.**

(Owen probably didn't think Anakin should be involved in the clone wars but that's because Owen was a simple moisture farmer (in a family of moisture farmers) who thought everyone should mind their own business.

In the movies, we never knew exactly what kind of words have been spoken between Obi-Wan Kenobi and Owen Lars since Obi-Wan arrived on Tatooine with baby Luke. However, we did see in the TV series *Obi-Wan Kenobi* that Owen wanted Kenobi to leave Luke alone and let him be raised ignorant of his past, repeatedly asking him to stop giving Luke toy spaceships and the like to play with and distract him from his chores around the farm.

Therefore this counts as a stretching of the truth or as misleading Luke, but not as an outright lie.)

**4. When Obi-Wan mentions that Luke will need to learn the Force if he's to come with Obi-Wan to Alderaan.**

(While this is true based on what Obi-Wan means (coming with him on his journey to defeat Darth Vader and the Emperor), it's a bit misleading because he doesn't mention any of these details. They're probably left out because they would discourage Luke, our *reluctant hero*, from leaving Tatooine. This is therefore misleading Luke at worst, and true at best)

---

All other lines Alec Guinness' Obi-Wan said *to Luke* are either true to the best of Obi-Wan's knowledge, matters of opinion, or otherwise not statements of testable veracity (commands, questions, *et cetera*).

Comment: Obi-Wan's comments to/about R2-D2 can be interpreted as intending to mislead Luke about whether Obi-Wan knows R2. (For what purpose, I don't know, which is why I tend to interpret those statements as 'genuine puzzlement' with a dash of 'leaving out the bits he doesn't want to explain', rather than any sort of intentionally-misleading statements.)

Comment: @Martha I disagree that it can be interpreted as Obi-Wan playing the fool. Obi-Wan's comment about never owning a droid comes off as genuine curiosity/bemusement to me, as well. Also consider that, in 1977, there *was* no prior relationship between Obi-Wan and R2-D2 or C-3P0.

Comment: @TylerH From a 1977 context, you're quite right. From a context that includes Ep 1 (per OP's question), Martha's right.

Comment: @Dronz I reject that clause from the OP as frivolous and unreasonable based on the main premise of the question.

Comment: @TylerH I sympathize. In fact, I'm tempted to ask the question "how much of Obi-Wan's lying is actually just Lucas changing his mind about the truth from film to film?" But that would be a rhetorical question, as really that's about me wishing he had been more self-consistent and made a bunch of films more like Episode IV and not like the prequels. :-)

Comment: @Dronz I've long wanted to make my own cut of Episode 1 removing Jar Jar and Midichlorians for similar reasons. Unfortunately Jar Jar is a central mcguffin to the plot of the first three movies and the entire Clone Wars.

Comment: @TylerH I've tried watching a few of the (now many) prequel re-edits. Some do things like cut all but one scene of Episode 1. Of those I saw, the one I liked best dubbed all the dialog into Japanese with subtitles so they could re-do the words: (The Blackened Mantle - https://youtu.be/lDLM-dXP-KE) But even then, it was hard for me to watch. I keep wanting it to be different. These quotes from Obi Wan in Episode IV evoke for me the possibility of such better films - they'd need to be completely re-imagined to live up to that.

Comment: "I understand you've become quite a good pilot yourself". During the briefing before the Battle of Yavin Luke says "I used to bullseye womp rats in my T60 back home. They're not much bigger than 2 meters". Biggs also calls him (from memory) "the best bush pilot in the outer territories".  So there is canon evidence that Kenobi's comment was accurate.

Answer (score 3):

> OBI-WAN: Your father wanted you to have this when you were old enough, but your uncle wouldn't allow it.

Maybe they had a conversation offscreen in time of Clone Wars, when Anakin said "If I will have a son, I wish to give him this lightsaber".

To prevent someone saying "Jedi are not allowed to have children, why would Anakin say it?" - Obi-Wan knew that Anakin and Padme were married as he came to her when he was looking for his former apprentice.

Comment: see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117191/why-did-obi-wan-tell-luke-his-father-wanted-him-to-have-his-lightsaber/117205#117205