# How many times was C-3PO less than honest with Luke?

Tags: star-wars, droids

*Related to this question:  [How many times was Obi-Wan less than honest with Luke?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112540/how-many-times-was-obi-wan-less-than-honest-with-luke)*

In *A New Hope*, when Luke asks 3PO to tell him about the rebellion, the droid replies:

> I'm not very good at telling stories.

But in *Return of the Jedi*, he recounts the events of the entire trilogy up to that point in a spellbinding manner, complete with almost perfect sound effects.  Clearly, his statement in ANH wasn't entirely true.

Later, when R2 refuses to play the video of Leia for Luke, 3PO conveys R2's lie that the recording had disappeared.  When Luke leaves the room, 3PO says:

> Just you reconsider playing that recording...

which makes it clear that he had covered for R2 by misleading Luke.

This calls his trustworthiness into question, in my opinion, so I am forced to ask:

### How many times was C-3PO less than honest with Luke in the Original Trilogy?

Comment: When he tells R2D2 to play the recording, Luke has already mentioned that he'd found a recording in his memory, but couldn't play it. He got the information about the presence of the recording from Luke.

Answer (score 1):

To his programming he wasn't lying, he was doing precisely what he was intended to do, interface two different protocols in a diplomatic manner.

In diplomacy you can't be upfront and blunt honest. You need to tell the truth in a way that isn't harmful. He didn't lie, because the data was lost as far as c3po was concerned because *depending on your point of view* he couldn't access it and for the moment was lost.

Comment: I'm not asking for an analysis limited to what he says in the quotes, and I don't care about justifications.  I'm asking how many times he says something that is *less than honest*.  See the linked question to get an idea of what I'm looking for.