# "Help me, Obi-Wan Kenobi" -- how does Leia know who Obi-Wan is?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, plot-device

So, in the opening scenes of A New Hope Princess Leia leaves a message for Obi-Wan Kenobi, asking her trusty plot-exposition droids to deliver it to an old recluse on a distant planet.

It is, at this stage, a closely guarded secret that

> Darth Vader is Luke Skywalker's father

and even more closely guarded that

> Darth Vader is Princess Leia's father

The recluse no longer goes by the name Obi-Wan, and claims he hasn't since before the birth of Leia and Luke.

- Leia is chasing shadows, asking droidle-dee and droidle-dum to find a man she's heard of in legend, in a place he's rumoured to be.
- Leia has had some kind of contact with Old Ben, he has used the name Obi-Wan in her lifetime, and he's a big fat liar (see [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112540/how-many-times-was-obi-wan-less-than-honest-with-luke)).
- She's got credible information from someone who was around beforehand that there's a bloke called Obi-Wan on Tatooine (a whole damn planet for the droids to search!?!), and that he can help.

Leia is pretty darned sure that Obi-Wan Kenobi is her only hope.

How the h-e-double-sippy-straws does she know who, or what, Obi-Wan Kenobi is?