# Was the Obi-Wan/Luke training scene in the Millennium Falcon a charade?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

Obi-Wan Kenobi has often been labeled as being less-than-truthful with Luke. With this in mind, let's take a look at a scene inside the Millennium Falcon in *Star Wars: A New Hope* (1977) where Luke was being trained by Obi-Wan while traveling to Alderaan.

After Obi-Wan tells Luke: "Stretch out with your feelings", we can perceive how Kenobi focuses his peculiar gaze on Luke's and the training droid's movements. Then, Luke manages to deflect three bolts from the droid.

I have always wondered if it could have been that Obi-Wan used the Force to make the droid aim at Luke's lightsaber, instead of his body, as a way to make his apprentice more confident with the Force that he does not yet understand; and in a similar manner, by saying he felt something and that almost saw the remote, Luke just made-up those statements to make his Master happy? In other words, was that training scene a charade?

[image: Still picture from Star Wars A New Hope (1977)]

Comment: interesting idea, but probably not, given what we do know about Luke's ability later in the film (he does use the Force to make his trench run shot). Also, in that moment, Luke shows much more confidence in using the saber than he had, almost as though he could indeed see the droid like he says he can. Your premise would also have Kenobi moving Luke as well. Also also- there isn't any indication in the first film that you can use the Force to physically manipulate objects, otherwise, why didn't Kenobi just use the Force to turn the dials on the tractor beam?

Comment: VTC as opinion based.  If this were canonically answerable, it would have been a big headline sometime in the past 44 years.

Comment: -1: Why do you say Obi-Wan Kenobi as an "untruthful" person. Thats a bald assertion, with no evidence to back this up.

Comment: @MoziburUllah https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112540/58193

Comment: FWIW I don't think this should be closed but I downvoted it. Whilst Obi-Wan may be less than truthful at times, I don't think it would make sense for him to trick Luke here. The point is to teach Luke to use the Force so tricking him into thinking he can when he can't may help in the short term but would probably set him back in the long term. Also it would kind of defeat the point of the scene for Obi-Wan to be tricking him.

Comment: @ZeissIkon This isn't opinion based and there's many resources to find an answer on the case. Also with your argument about it making a big headline, that would only have been the case if he had been tricking Luke which may not actually be the case.

Comment: if Luke was skeptic (about the force), it would've been plausible for Obi-Wan to trick Luke.  However he, just like his father Anakin,  without any hesitation accepted that *the force was strong with him*and believed Obi-Wan. Old-bi-Wan didn't need anything to *motivate* Luke by tricking him.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [junior novelization](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_(junior_novelization)) of *A New Hope*:

> He stopped thinking about the remote, just stopped thinking and relaxed, and... somehow, he sensed the remote's proximity. Stranger still, he seemed able to anticipate its movement through the air. Despite his blocked vision, Luke moved fast with his lightsaber and deftly parried each shot.

This explicitly describes Luke being able to sense the remote and predict where it was going.

Comment: Thanks @Milo P. With you answer now I believe that I wasn't a charade but Luke's first step into a larger world!